# Hypothesis testing with binomial test vs Chi2

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

Is it valid to test the following hypothesis with a binomial test? Or should a chi2-test be applied in this case?

A factory produces different products (A-G) with different rates of production errors in % (i.e., a product can be defect or okay). The question of interest is, if a newly introduced product is more prone to production errors than the average of the old products:

```r
Product  Total  % error
A        28     14
B        49     10
C        33     6
D        44     9
E        68     10
F        28     10
G        55     14

New      60     12
```

Thus my hypothesis would be:

```
H0: There is no difference in production errors (avg(A-G) ~= New)
H1: New product is more error prone (New > avg(A-G))
```

Then my intuition would be to apply a simple binomial test

```
Avg error % = (0.14 * 28) + (0.10 * 49)+ (0.06*33)+ (0.09*44) + 
              (0.1*68)+ (0.1*28) + (0.14*55) / 305   ==> 0.105
```

```py
from scipy.stats import binom_test
binom_test(x=12, n=60, p=0.105, alternative="greater")  ==> 0.02
```

Which would tell me that there is a statistically significant different thus I could reject H0.

Is it valid to test in this way or would a chi2-test be more suited? Or are there even other possibilities to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the binomial test is that you are treating the *estimated* proportion 0.105 among the old products as known, while it is estimated. Also, how you have calculated the test is in error, because 12 is a percent, while you have used is at the number of errors. A correct test would be

```r
binom.test(7, 60, p=0.105, alternative="greater")

    Exact binomial test

data:  7 and 60
number of successes = 7, number of trials = 60, p-value = 0.4443
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.105
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05605488 1.00000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.1166667
```

The chi-squared test is not really appropriate, since it tests a different hypothesis, and in principle could reject because of differences among the old, and not differences between old and new. Let us try:

```r
with(mydata, chisq.test( cbind(nerror, Total-nerror)))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  cbind(nerror, Total - nerror)
X-squared = 2.1033, df = 7, p-value = 0.9539
```

(see code below for definitions). We could avoid these by collapsing the first 7 rows of the table:

```r
ctable <- rbind( apply(mydata[1:7, c(2, 4)], 2, sum), 
                 mydata[8, c(2, 4)])
> ctable
  Total nerror
1   305     33
8    60      7
> chisq.test(ctable)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  ctable
X-squared = 1.6109e-30, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

But what I would prefer is first doing a logistic regression, and then define a contrast and testing the contrast.  With R code:

```r
mod0 <- glm(cbind(nerror, Total-nerror) ~ 0 + Product, 
            family=binomial, data=mydata) 
> 
> car:::linearHypothesis(mod0, hypothesis.matrix= c(rep(1/7, 7), -1), 
                         coef.=coef(mod0), vcov.=vcov(mod0))
Error in linearHypothesis.default(model, ...) : residual df = 0
```

So we do it by hand:

```r
c <- c(rep(-1/7, 7), 1)
bhat <- coef(mod0)
V <- vcov(mod0) 

sum(c*bhat) / sqrt(t(c) %*% V %*% c)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2841532
```

This computes an approximate z-test of the hypothesis that the average of coefficients for the old products (7)  is equal to the coefficient for the new. It is not significant at any conventional level.

Code for  reading the data:

```r
textdata <-   
  "
Product  Total  perror
A        28     14
B        49     10
C        33     6
D        44     9
E        68     10
F        28     10
G        55     14

New      60     12
"
mydata <- read.table(textConnection(textdata), header=TRUE)

mydata <- within(mydata, nerror <- round(Total*perror/100))  
mydata <- within(mydata, Product <- factor(Product))
```